# How to Find the 4 furthest points of this rectangle

Tags: matlab, max, min, rectangles, corner-detection

I have plotted a list of corners I've obtained using Harris Corner detection.

[image]

Now I need to find the 4 furthers points that will represent the corners of the rectangle

I know I can get the two top and bottom diagonal corners using

```
  max(C);
  min(C);
```

Where C is an n row matrix with a column for x and y like

```
  x y
  0 1
  2 3
  4 5
  6 6
```

But how do I get the other two corners?

I thought I could rotate the matrix and use min and max again, but of course that just returns me a huge n column matrix (and I want a 2 column matrix)

I feel like the answer is obvious, but I'm blanking :(

Comment: What do the rows of `C` represent? Coordinates on the boundary? Points within the white area? The black area? Using `min` and `max` like you do is very dangerous, because there's no guarantee that the returned values belong to the same corner. Is your input a black and white image, or this `C`? Would you upload the raw inputs available to you (whether it's a BW image or a limited-size matrix)..?

Comment: Rows of C are coordinates of the result of the Harris corner detection, Rows of C are the coordinates of the blue points in the image I posted.
So I guess I don't actually have ANY of the points, if max is returning the max value from each col. :'(

Comment: Here is a link to the data points (way bigger than I realized)
http://jmp.sh/v/8lAytDc00UrOa17Z6Oo6

Comment: Try writing down mathematically how you would define a corner coordinate. For instance you could have detected a corner which is further left than the actual lower-left corner, because you minimised the x coordinate...

Comment: I aksed my question a different way and posted here.

http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72407/given-a-large-set-of-x-y-coordinates-choose-4-of-the-coordinates-to-make-a-po 

 I'm going to sleep on it. Hopefully it will be obvious in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how limited is the following method but it worked for an example similar to yours:

```
% detect possible corners
points = detectHarrisFeatures(BW);
C = points.Location;
% compute par-wise distances between all points
D = pdist2(C,C);
p = zeros(1,4);
% compute maximum distance to find first pair
[m,idx1] = max(D,[],2);
[~,idx2] = max(m);
idx1 = idx1(idx2);
p(1:2) = [idx1, idx2];
% add first pair distance to distance matrix so the next pair will be
% distant from this pair as well, and compute max distance again
D = bsxfun(@plus,D,sum(D([idx1 idx2],:),1));
[m,idx1] = max(D,[],2);
[~,idx2] = max(m);
idx1 = idx1(idx2);
p(3:4) = [idx1, idx2];
% plot
imshow(BW);
hold on;
plot(C(:,1),C(:,2),'g.');
plot(C(p,1),C(p,2),'rx','LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

another option is to use FEX functions like [Polygon simplification](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45342-polygon-simplification) and [Decimate Polygon](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34639-decimate-polygon), and to set the number of desired vertexes to 4.

Comment: NB: This uses the Computer Vision Toolbox (i.e. `detectHarrisFeatures`).  The OP may not have access to this.

Comment: true. this was just to get an example set of possible points as the OP already have.

Comment: Agreed! I still like it though.  I would have approached this with Harris Corners myself.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution, if you dont want to use corner detection:

```
im=zeros(100);

im(40:70,30:80)=1;
im=imrotate(im,rand*100);

[x,y]=find(im);
x=x+2*randn(size(x));
y=y+2*randn(size(y));
X=[x(:),y(:)]; 

d=ceil(pdist2(X,X)*10)/10;

[a,b]=find(d==max(d(:))); 

xm=x(a);
ym=y(a);

figure,plot(x,y,'ks')
hold on, plot(xm,ym,'ro','MarkerSize',12,'MArkerFaceColor','r')
axis image
```

[image]

Comment: NB: `pdist2` requires the Statistics Toolbox.